# HTML image display set to none later won't show up when set to block

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web game that's playable on both desktop and mobile. Playing on mobile devices requires the user to play in landscape mode.

I did a simple check on device orientation via width versus height, and I'm supposed to show an image telling the player to rotate the device. So I added this to the html file:

```
<div id="rotateWarning"><img src="res/plsRotate.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></div>
```

This has the problem of showing the image by default. The user would have to rotate the phone to portrait mode if it were in landscape mode, and back again. Worse, it also shows by default on Desktop browsers, and there's no way to rotate that. The code does work though, hiding the image when it's rotated the right way.

So the alternative is to set it to `display: none` by default, right?

The problem with that is that it never shows. It seems once set to `display: none`, it ignores every attempt to change it.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Alternatively, is there a better way to implement this idea?

Edit:

Here's my HTML file:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('resize', onSizeChange);
</script>
```

And here's my function:

```
function onSizeChange() {
    if (getMobileOperatingSystem) {
        if (window.outerHeight > window.outerWidth) {
            document.getElementById('rotateWarning').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('logInPages').style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            console.log("Landscape!");
            document.getElementById('rotateWarning').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('logInPages').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you set it to display: none, what attempts are you making in order to change it, when a rotation happens?

Comment: Assuming you're only targeting "modern" browsers, [media queries](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-3/) are probably a better way to go. There are also DOM-based APIs available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries

Comment: setting `display : block` should ideally work. Please show us the code where you are attempting to set it to `block`. Perhaps you are not selecting the right DOM element

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari I've updated the question.

Comment: @ChrisCousins I've update the question.

Comment: Did u try putting a console in the `if` block too and see if it gets printed. Also are you sure there is no other code which might get execute after this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the **[`orientation` media feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation)** to hide and show the relevant element based on the orientation of the device. You'll want to *hide* the element by default, and *show* the element for portrait orientations. The element will re-display for portrait devices due to increased **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**.

```css
#rotateWarning {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  #rotateWarning {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="rotateWarning">
  <img src="res/plsRotate.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
</div>
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, thanks, seems like a more 'modern' solution. How does the "orientation: portrait" work? The reason I went with size instead of orientation is that some devices are landscape by default; in JavaScript, orientation just gets the angle, and this would screw up the logic.

Comment: The link in the answer provides pretty good information on `orientation`. Is there something that is not clear from that link?

Comment: @JonP I recently tested this on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S. On landscape mode, it does show the warning image meant for portrait mode (also logged, for good measure). We're back to square one, it seems, though the rest of the logic of this answer is applicable.